# Netsuite: Create password policy for Customer in website registration

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am building an ecommerce site using Netsuite Site Builder. I want to enforce my custom password policy for customer registration page.

According to this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSATH/NSATH.pdf) (see Page 8), it states that *"Netsuite password policies and requirements (other than the requirement for a minimum password length of 6 characters) do not apply to customers"*

Also according to this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSCSB/NSCSB.pdf) (see page 37), we can customize the registration form by which it meant that we can only add any additional fields to the existing registration form.

How can I implement custom password policy for customer registration form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to put the code into your theme and detect when the customer is on the password entry page. Then you can put an event handler on the password field and do your own validation.

I've used this strategy for such things as password policy validation and duplicate password detection.